# Journal title present in .bib but missing in .bbl

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bbl

The journal title form my .bib file does not get transferred to the .bbl file. Here's an entry from the .bib file:

```
@article{bangor09determining,
  title = {Determining {{What Individual SUS Scores Mean}}: {{Adding}} an {{Adjective Rating Scale}}},
  volume = {4},
  issn = {1931-3357},
  shorttitle = {Determining {{What Individual SUS Scores Mean}}},
  abstract = {[removed for conciseness]},
  timestamp = {2016-06-18T00:12:06Z},
  number = {3},
  journaltitle = {J. Usability Studies},
  author = {Bangor, Aaron and Kortum, Philip and Miller, James},
  date = {2009-05},
  pages = {114--123},
  keywords = {surveys,SUS,system usability scale,usability,user satisfaction},
  file = {ACM Full Text PDF:/Users/file/path/removed/for/privacy.pdf}
}
```

And the corresponding entry from the .bbl file:

```
\bibitem{bangor09determining}
Bangor, A., Kortum, P., Miller, J.: Determining {{What Individual SUS Scores
  Mean}}: {{Adding}} an {{Adjective Rating Scale}}  4(3),  114--123
```

The journal title is missing from the .bbl entry. How can I get the journal title to be placed in the .bbl file? How is the .bib file translated to a .bbl file, and what kinds of settings could there be that would determine which fields get included in the .bbl?

Comment: Which bibliography style are you using? Try using some other. If problem persists, post a minimum example showing your problem.

Answer (score 9):

`journaltitle` is a field in `biblatex` not `bibtex`, but `\bibitem`s (and the format given in the OP) indicate that the bibliography is created by `bibtex` and not by `biblatex`.

The corresponding field `bibtex` is `journal` (which is also recognised by `biblatex`), thus one can look for `journaltitle` in a `.bib` and replace them with `journal` (or configure the bib manager to perform such substitution).

While `biblatex` is able to handle both the `journal` and `journaltitle`, standard `bibtex` style can only handle `journal`.  However, it is possible to modify a `bibtex` style to handle `journaltitle`. Here is the procedure:

Make a copy of the `bibtex` style (extension `.bst`) and rename it. If the file for the style is `<style>.bst` rename it in `my<style>.bst`.

Open `my<style>.bst` and search for

```
ENTRY {
  ...
  journal 
  ...
}
```

and `jorunaltitle` in the line after `journal`. Thus you should have something like

```
ENTRY {
   ...
   journal
   journaltitle 
   ...
}
```

This instruction tells `bibtex` that `journaltitle` is a field to parse.

Locate the function

```
FUNCTION {format.title} 
{
  <definition of the function>
}
```

Change the function as follows:

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ journaltitle empty$
    { <old  definition of the function> }
    { <instructions for title in the old defintion> }
  if$
}
```

For example, if the `format.title` function is

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$
    }
  if$
}
```

the revised definition should look like:

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ journaltitle empty$
    { title empty$
        { "" }
        { title "t" change.case$
        }
      if$
    }
    { journaltitle "t" change.case$ }
  if$
}
```

The  definition looks, whether there is a value for the field `journaltitle`, and there apply the same formatting instruction as `title`. If there is no value, then it check if there is a value for the  field `title`. If so, it apply the old definition.

Comment: One might add that BibTeX will also have problems with the `date` field. For BibTeX one should give the date in the `year` and `month` fields.

Comment: Helpful answer! But are you sure it's not the other way around? I was originally using biblatex but after switching to bibtex the ```journaltitle``` field is now recognized.

Comment: @dinosaur Yes, I'm sure. The format of bibliography indicates that you are not using `biblatex` in that case and that it has been created by `bibtex`.

Comment: This seems like a huge design flaw. Has anyone found a work-around that allows biblatex to interpret `journaltitle` as `journal`?

Comment: @kilojoules - biblatex and biber know full well what to do with a field called `\journaltitle` if it occurs in an entry of type `@article`. It is BibTeX -- at least when used with one of the "standard" bibliography styles -- that doesn't know what to do with the `journaltitle` field.

Comment: @Mico thanks for this correction. Please consider my question to be regarding bibtex's interpretation of `journaltitle`. This has created problems for me using the Zotero reference manager, as it uses `journaltitle` and I am compiling with bibtex.

Comment: @kilojoules - Thanks for this clarification. Which bibliography style do you use? And, do you use a citation management package such as `natbib`? Please advise.

Comment: @kilojoules - Do look into modifying Zotero's settings. One of the choices you can make is to inform Zotero whether you will be using BibTeX or biblatex. If you choose BibTeX, you should get all entries of type `@article` with fields named `journal`, `year`, and `month` rather than `journaltitle` and `date`.

Comment: @kilojoules Guido has kindly provided a guide on how to make BibTeX cope with `journaltitle` as well, but I would not go through the hassle of changing `.bst` files for that. `journal` has be the field name for the journal (title) from the (from BibTeX's) start. So it is the universally used and accepted name here (if only by custom), `biblatex` internally calls the field `journaltitle` (for naming consistency), but fully supports inputs with `journal` by aliasing`journal` to `journaltitle`. So many still use `journal` - it's shorter and one is used to it. ...

Comment: ... If your favourite literature manager exports `journaltitle` it should be fully aware that it is producing output for `biblatex` which may be (in parts) backwards-incompatible with how BibTeX used to do things in the olden days (and today still!). There should be an option to 'go back to standard BibTeX mode'. Mico mentions another issue: that of `year`, `month`, `day` in BibTeX which is replaced by `date` in `biblatex`. BibTeX normally does not understand `date`, while `biblatex` has limited support for `year` and `month`, but ignores `day`.

Comment: ... Note that when I say 'BIbTeX' I mean 'many standard `.bst` files'. In theory there *could* be `.bst` files that  understand `date`, but to my knowledge there aren't. The great majority of `.bst`s shares a similar data scheme.